# Javascript movement delay on initial keypress (3D)

Tags: javascript, three.js, keycode, gltf

I want the movement to be smooth upon pressing a key, the object does an initial movement and then starts moving completely when holding down the button.

```
//movement speed
var xSpeed = 0.5;
var zSpeed = 0.5;

document.addEventListener("keydown", onDocumentKeyDown, false);

function onDocumentKeyDown(event) {
  var keyCode = event.which;
  if (keyCode == 87) {  //W KEY
    car.position.z -= zSpeed;
  } else if (keyCode == 83) {  //S KEY
    car.position.z += zSpeed;
  } else if (keyCode == 65) {  //A KEY
    car.position.x -= xSpeed;
  } else if (keyCode == 68) {  //D KEY
    car.position.x += xSpeed;
  } else if (keyCode == 32) {
    car.position.set(0, 0, 0);
  }
};
```

Trying to get a GLTF imported model to be controlled on a plane with keyboard controls smoothly.
Tried wrapping the program in a loop and made the state of the keyboard available inside the scope of that loop but couldn't get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try an approach where the velocity is modified upon keyup/keydown, and the loop just modifies the car's position based on the velocity.

```js
// initial movement speed
var xSpeed = 0;
var zSpeed = 0;

document.addEventListener("keydown", onDocumentKeyDown, false);
document.addEventListener("keydown", onDocumentKeyUp, false);

function onDocumentKeyDown(event) {
  var keyCode = event.which;
  if (keyCode == 87) {  //W KEY
    zSpeed = -0.5;
  } ... // do so for the rest of the keys
};


function onDocumentKeyUp(event) {
  var keyCode = event.which;
  if (keyCode == 87) {  //W KEY
    zSpeed = 0;
  } ... // do so for the rest of the keys
};

function loop() {
car.position.z += zSpeed;
car.position.x += xSpeed;
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

If you are interested in more eased movement, e.g. the car doesn't just start moving at constant velocity but ramps up and slows down, consider having the keyup/keydown modify an acceleration factor, and the loop modifies the velocity.

This is a good in-depth article by Daniel Shiffman about attempting to represent the real world with code:
https://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-1-vectors/